# java.net.SocketException while creating spring starter project in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am facing java.net.SocketException while creating a spring starter project. The project details are in the below image:
[image]

but when I click on finish button I get the below error popup:
[image]

I checked the error logs and found the detailed error there:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.importing.MavenStrategy$MavenCodeSetImport.run(MavenStrategy.java:90)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.NewSpringBootWizardModel.performFinish(NewSpringBootWizardModel.java:354)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.NewSpringBootWizard$1.run(NewSpringBootWizard.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3368)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.util.IOUtil.pipe(IOUtil.java:51)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.downloadmanager.SimpleDownloadService.fetch(SimpleDownloadService.java:58)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.downloadmanager.DownloadManager.downloadFile(DownloadManager.java:143)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.downloadmanager.DownloadManager.doWithDownload(DownloadManager.java:194)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.downloadmanager.DownloadableItem.getFile(DownloadableItem.java:65)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.content.ZipFileCodeSet.each(ZipFileCodeSet.java:135)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.content.CodeSet.createAt(CodeSet.java:168)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.importing.MavenStrategy$MavenCodeSetImport.run(MavenStrategy.java:77)
    ... 3 more
Root exception:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3368)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.util.IOUtil.pipe(IOUtil.java:51)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.downloadmanager.SimpleDownloadService.fetch(SimpleDownloadService.java:58)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.downloadmanager.DownloadManager.downloadFile(DownloadManager.java:143)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.downloadmanager.DownloadManager.doWithDownload(DownloadManager.java:194)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.downloadmanager.DownloadableItem.getFile(DownloadableItem.java:65)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.content.ZipFileCodeSet.each(ZipFileCodeSet.java:135)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.content.CodeSet.createAt(CodeSet.java:168)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.importing.MavenStrategy$MavenCodeSetImport.run(MavenStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.NewSpringBootWizardModel.performFinish(NewSpringBootWizardModel.java:354)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.NewSpringBootWizard$1.run(NewSpringBootWizard.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error. The same was working few days back.

Comment: i guess STS is not able to connect to spring servers.. verify if firewall is blocking any spring related sites.. not sure exactly which server they conenct to

Comment: firewall is turned off.

Comment: are you in corporate network? are you using a recent sts?

Comment: Yes I am using latest version : STS 3.8.4.RELEASE.
Yes I am in corporate network, but I was able to do the same stuffs few days back in corporate network as well.

Comment: can you pls check if you are able to access http://start.spring.io and you are able to download a starter project from there?

Comment: Though I am able to access http://start.spring.io/ but faling Network error while downloading the project. Can you please help me in resolving this.

Comment: your corporate firewall might be the culprit.. which is blocking the download.. check with your IT team if you can get an exception this.. or try to build a maven project and add the spring boot dependencies manually..

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue but the difference was, I was using the url with https like https://start.spring.io/ which was causing same error.

[image]

I tried this url in to browser and able to access the Spring Starter.

When I changed the URL to http  like http://start.spring.io/ in eclipse it's start working and I could create the required Project as well.

[image]